# How to receive the push notification on my iPhone application from Facebook service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, push-notification, real-time-updates

I'm going to build my own iPhone application.
What I need is to receive the push notification on my application from Facebook service when some actions occur - of course, the actions on Facebook.

I have found the "Real-time Updates"(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) from the internet, but it needs the third party web service.
I have not it, so what's the solution?

Is there no solution to receive the notifications from Facebook service directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the solution you are proposing is that Facebook would have to track your app's bundle identifier, and keep your push notification token, and then it would be responsible for sending the push to the APN servers. It's something that they probably don't want to do for themselves.

Having a dedicated web service for the app means you're responsible for all of that.